# GeoServer Map with streets (sketch map)

Tags: gis, geoserver

Can someone explain me how to create sketch map in geoserver with street title, roads and etc. for my gps tracking system ? 
I found a `landsat8` space images but I can't understand how to work with it. When I load it to my geoserver it shows a only pic without a street and etc.

Comment: What do you mean by a "sketch map"? if all you load is a satellite image then that is all you will see, GeoServer can't do magic for you. If you want street names and roads you will need to add some other data sets.

Comment: Which data sets ?

Comment: any data sets that you want to use, may be open street map